# Pi4 RTS pin big delay

Tags: python, serial, modbus

I am trying to use modbus with RS485 on my Pi4. I'm using modbus_tk with pySerial library, and I managed to get controllig RTS pin while transmitting data, but I cant get it running faster - when TX ends the pins stays UP for aprox. 30ms (25 +- 35) after TX.

[image: ,]

My code below:

```
socket = serial.rs485.RS485(port=PORT, baudrate=460800, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, rtscts=True, dsrdtr=False, timeout=0.01, xonxoff=0 )
socket.rs485_mode = serial.rs485.RS485Settings(rts_level_for_tx=True, rts_level_for_rx=False, loopback=False, delay_before_tx=0, delay_before_rx=0)

master = modbus_rtu.RtuMaster(socket)

master.set_timeout(2.0)
master.set_verbose(True)
def readAll():
    try:
        data = master.execute(1, cst.READ_HOLDING_REGISTERS, 999, 55)
        os.system('clear')
        print(datetime.now())
        print("IsolInputs: ", data[0:4])
        print("ADCInputs: ", data[4:21])
        print("ADCInputs_raw: ", data[21:37])
        print("RelayOtuputs: ", data[37:43])
        print("PWMFrequency: ", data[43])
        print("PWMDutyCycle: ", data[44:54])
        print("DevStatus: ", data[54])

    except modbus_tk.modbus.ModbusError as exc:
        logger.error("%s- Code=%d", exc, exc.get_exception_code())
```

I tried to manually control another GPIO Pin via hooks in modbus_tk lib, but it gives me the simmilar result:

```
def on_before_write(args):
    GPIO.output(EN_485, GPIO.HIGH)
hooks.install_hook("modbus.Master.before_send", on_before_write)

def on_after_write(args):
    GPIO.output(EN_485,  GPIO.LOW)
hooks.install_hook("modbus.Master.after_send", on_after_write)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain why this is a problem? RTS means the host (in this case: the Pi) is ready to send data. In theory, this could stay high forever.

Comment: @PMF i Wanat i to control rs485 hałf duplex, and if it’s high for too long my slaves need to wait with response - this makes my program running too long.

Comment: I see... So for your case the timeout for resetting RTS is to long. One possibility would be to use an NE555 and manually derive a (short) timeout from the data line.

Comment: I noticed that if i manyally send only one message it works perfectly, but when I do it in loop it makes problem like that.

Comment: Would adding `ser.setRTS(False)` as soon as possible in your script help?

Comment: @Andyroo unfortunately I is not possible in my script, because modbus_tk library controls pySerial writing. But I will check it on some other script, and confirm that.